# Create a sub menu in existing menu in Excel Shared Add-in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, shared-addin

I am developing a Excel shared Add-in which has the menu called `Custom` which is created using Excel Macros. Now i want to create a submenu under the `Custom` menu using Csharp Shared Add -in. Iam using the below code for doing this but no help

```
oStandardBar = oCommandBars["Custom"];
oCmdBarCtrl = oStandardBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
oCmdBarCtrl.Visible = false;
oCmdBarCtrl.Caption = "Sub Menu1";
```

But it does not create a submenu, where as if i give "Help" in place of Custom i get the menu created. any work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick sample to help you on your way:

```
        var m_toolbar = this.Application.CommandBars.Add("WpfAddIn",
            Office.MsoBarPosition.msoBarTop, false, true);

        var mainMenu = (Office.CommandBarPopup)m_toolbar.Controls
            .Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, 
            missing, missing, missing, true);
        mainMenu.Caption = "Main menu";

        var subMenu1 = (Office.CommandBarButton)mainMenu.Controls
            .Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 
            missing, missing, missing, true);
        subMenu1.Caption = "Sub menu 1";
        subMenu1.FaceId = 1958;

        var subMenu2 = (Office.CommandBarPopup)mainMenu.Controls
            .Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup,
            missing, missing, missing, true);
        subMenu2.BeginGroup = true;
        subMenu2.Caption = "Sub menu 2";

        var subMenu2Button = (Office.CommandBarButton)subMenu2.Controls
            .Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
            missing, missing, missing, true);
        subMenu2Button.Caption = "Sub menu 1";
        subMenu2Button.FaceId = 1958;

        m_toolbar.Visible = true;
```